# $\mathbf{x^TDx}+\mathbf{b^Tx}=0\; \Rightarrow\;\exists!\left\{\mathbf{x}=0 \;\oplus\;\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{D^-b}\right\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider $$\mathbf{x^TDx}+\mathbf{b^Tx}=0 \tag 1.$$

Let $\mathbf{D}$ is full rank diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{b} \neq 0$.

Then solutions $\mathbf{x}=0 \;\text{and}\;\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{D^{-1}b}$ exist.

**Question.** Are there conditions that equation $(1)$ has another solutions?

**Updated**

Consider
$$\left\{ \begin{align} \mathbf{y^TD_1y}+\mathbf{b_1^Ty}=0 \\ \mathbf{y^TD_2y}+\mathbf{b_2^Ty}=0 \end{align} \right. \tag 2$$

I believed that the system $(2)$ has a root if there are true conditions that an equation $(1)$ has another solutions, for example, $\mathbf{x}$ has infinite set of values.

Where did I make a mistake?

**Updated**

Really equation $(1)$ has another solutions, for example in $\mathbb{R^2}$, next root (not only)

$$
\mathbf{x}=\left[\frac{-b_1+\sqrt{-4d_1d_2x^2_2-4b_2d_1x_2+b_1^2}} {2d_1}\;,x_2\right]^\mathbf{T}
$$

Comment: Do you consider $x=-D^{-1}b$ to be a "trivial" solution?

Comment: Yes. Is it error?

Comment: In the standard terminology, the *trivial* solution of $Ax=0$ is $x=0$. It may cause a misunderstanding.

Comment: Understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick *any* $x_0$ with $x_0^TDx_0\ne 0$ and $b^Tx_0\ne 0$ and consider the line $tx_0$. On this line
$$
t^2x_0^TDx_0+tb^Tx_0=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad t=0\text{ or } t=-\frac{b^Tx_0}{x_0^TDx_0}\ne 0.
$$
The second $t$ corresponds to a non-trivial solution $tx_0$, so there is a solution in almost all directions $x_0$.

Comment: Every quadic can be derived in this *diagonal* form .
Thus, is every system of quadrics an inconsistent if $\mathbf{b}\neq 0$ and $D$ has full rank?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by inconsistent. Your equation defines a quadric. Full rank, hence, elliptic or hyperbolic. It is huge amount of points in the space. There is no way it is only *two points* $x=0$ and $x=-D^{-1}b$.

Comment: Really equation $(1)$ has another solutions, for example in $\mathbb{R^2}$, next root (not only)

$$
\mathbf{x}=\left[\frac{-b_1+\sqrt{-4d_1d_2x^2_2-4b_2d_1x_2+b_1^2}} {2d_1}\;,x_2\right]^\mathbf{T}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is diagonal and full rank, you know for sure that it is invertible, so such solution $\mathbb{x}=-D^{-1}b$ exists.

Comment: $\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{D^-b}$ is trivial. Are there anothers?

Comment: @AnnaSdTC Not true. It is possible that $x$ is orthogonal to $Dx+b$. For example, $b=0$, $D=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @A.G. Yes, you are right. I'm going to delete my comment.